# advice for best data type for a large lookup table (4d->4d) in python

Tags: python, pandas

Right now I have data that is in a 4d numpy array, say `old_data[i1, i2, i3, i4]` (entries are float numbers), and I want to construct an 1-to-1 lookup table `LUT: (i1, i2, i3, i4) -> (j1, j2, j3, j4)` so that I can transfer the values from `old_data[i1, i2, i3, i4]` into `new_data[j1, j2, j3, j4]` later on.

Question is: what is the best data type or practice to construct/save `LUT`?

#### Possible solutions:

1. A `dict` of key/value pairs of `i's/j's`
2. A 4d numpy array of entries like lists `[j1, j2, j3, j4]` or tuples `(j1, j2, j3, j4)`
3. Or something else?

#### 2 points to keep in mind:

1. the indexing should be easy when I transfer from `old_data` to `new_data`
2. the number of entry is large, ~1 billion. i.e. `i1 * i2 * i3 *i4 ~ 1 billion`

Comment: Do you have any structure in the mapping? Without that, you will need som 16 GB to store the mapping only.

Comment: The structure of mapping, LUT, is exactly what I'm looking for. I don't know what would be a better way of implementing it

Comment: I don't understand. Can you do one-to-one mapping?

Comment: It IS a 1-to-1 mapping, as I said in the post. But it could be implemented in different forms right? whether it's a `dict`, like `{(i1, i2, i3, i4): (j1, j2, j3, j4)`, or a 4d array of list, like `LUT[i1, i2, i3, i4] = [j1, j2, j3, j4]`, or something else

Comment: OK, what I meant was if you could just implicitly map the stuctures by storing the data at the same offsets in the different structures, so that wast is stored in e.g. if `i1 = 2` then also `j1 = 2`and so on. Is that an option?